# JSF Custom component renders in index page, but not in a page within a folder

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am using Java Server Faces, Java EE, NetBeans. I want to display a custom component on a page within a faces flow. This component displays fine on the index.xhtml page in the Web Pages folder, however the same code will not render the component on Web Pages/registration/registration.xhtml

I am having similar issues getting a template to work on these pages within the folder.

Comment: read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Whaaahahahahaaahaaahaaaaa....ROTFLMAO. The moment you spend as much time as me TRYING TO HELP on SO, you have a valid point... If, for everybody (and there are a lot), would spend the time YOU want me to spend on it, I'd have a non-paid 24x7 job. If you don't understand what is written in [ask] and [mcve] and cannot (or will not) understand why this is needed and only can give a midllefinger... well... Then I am sorry for you... Really am... Flagged your comment for moderator attention. Not sure what they'll do with it... Cheers!